# onDestroy or onPause not called in a TabHosts child activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a Tabhost and in that tabhost there are 4 tabs and in every tab there is an activity. When an activity lose focus i want to catch it with onDestroy or onPause method.

What I have tried?

1. `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` - this method calls onDestroy of the child activity when a tab gain focus (?!*%>) and then calls onCreate of the child activity.
2. I have overrided nearly all protected functions of the lifecycle and also `finish()`. But nothing happened.
3. I have tried TabHosts `onTabChanged` function but i cant retrieve any activity from tabhost and i cant call any `finish()`-like function so it failed too.

Please help me with this situation!! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

By the way I am extending Activity not TabActivity.

Comment: It's the parent activity, TabActivity which gets called on those overrided methods onPause(), onDestroy() etc.

Comment: Ok but could I expain my question? I have a timer in a child activity (in the TabHost). I want to catch the situation that lose focus from that activity to stop it.

Comment: Do you mean like when you switch to another tab you want to stop it?

Comment: Or when the TabActivity is completely destroyed?

Comment: Yes exactly! when tab changed to different activity i want to stop previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (currentActivity instanceof TheActivity) {
            // do nothing, we are here!
        }
        else { 
            ((TheActivity) currentActivity).methodToStopTimer();
        }
    }
});
```

or the most common way

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (!currentActivity instanceof TheActivity) {
            ((TheActivity) currentActivity).methodToStopTimer();
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: from top of my head I thought that method was part of TabHost, but never mind, just check the tabId so you know which activity you are in:

```
if(!tabId.equals("idForYourActivity")){
    ActivityName.methodToStopTimer();
}
```

You will need to have the `methodToStopTimer()` to be static.

Comment: getCurrentActivity() and TheActivity are not recognized by the Activity

Comment: "TheActivity" is the just a name I came up with, there you should put the name of your Activity which has the timer.

Comment: Thats ok. But what with getCurrentActivity()?

Comment: yes it worked! But I have to know one thing before marking as an answer :p All my variables are now static variables. Are there any problem with a handler or runnable to be static variable?

Comment: No problem at all. Static variables just live longer, but you won't even see difference in memory management. You can google yourself and look up the meaning of static variables.

Comment: yes i know the meaning what is a static variable. But only asked for timers, just a curious question.

Comment: Okey I see, yeah no problem there either :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in onStop() Rather than on destroy; It suits your scenario:) Try and tel:) cheers

Comment: Are you Using Explicit Intent to Switch Between tabs? If so then call finish before the statement `startActivity(intent)`, then use onStop()

Comment: I m intenting with setContent(intent) to the tabhost with TabSpec